# Delete Item from array

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

How can I delete a "FolderName" item from **directoryPaths** array? Not physically from the path, only from **directoryPaths**.

```
string[] directoryPaths = Directory.GetDirectories(@path);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this change in place by finding the element that you wish to delete (say, at index `del`), move all elements *after* `del` down by one index, and then resize the array down by calling `Array.Resize`:

```
int del = Array.IndexOf(directoryPaths, @path+"\\Desktop Files"); // Pick an index to delete
for (int i = del+1 ; i != directoryPaths.Length ; i++) {
    directoryPaths[i-1] = directoryPaths[i];
}
Array.Resize(directoryPaths.Length-1);
```

Comment: But I don`t know the index of the folder because is not the same every time. I only know the name.

Comment: @SebastianCorneliuVîrlan You can use `IndexOf` method to find the index (see the edit).

Comment: int del = Array.IndexOf(directoryPaths, "Desktop Files"); is -1 . So is correct to use Desktop Files or should I provide full path?

Comment: @SebastianCorneliuVîrlan Print out the values in a loop, and see which string represents the path that you want deleted. Then supply that path to `IndexOf` as the second parameter.

Comment: int del = Array.IndexOf(directoryPaths, @path+"\\Desktop Files"); please modify the post to make as Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use List, instead of array.

```
var directoryPaths = Directory.GetDirectories((@path).ToList(); 
directoryPaths.Remove(FolderName);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Linq;

var paths = directoryPaths
  .Where(p => p != folderName)
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: Is correct if: `var directoryPaths = directoryPathsx
                  .Where(p => p != @path + "\\Desktop Files")
                  .ToArray();`